# simplexml_load_file odd behavior

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a file (sites.txt) that has two entries:

```
http://www.url1.com/test1.xml
http://www.url2.com/test2
```

Whenever I execute the below PHP code, the 'url1.com' returns false, and the 'url2.com' is loaded into `$xml`.  The odd part is that if I interchange the URLs in the file, i.e.

```
http://www.url2.com/test2
http://www.url1.com/test1.xml
```

It loads both. Both URLs are valid XML documents. Why does the order matter here?

Code:

```
if (file_exists('sites.txt')) {
    $file_handle = fopen("sites.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $site  = fgets($file_handle);
        $xml[] = simplexml_load_file($site);
}
fclose($file_handle);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a foreach loop to iterate over the lines of the file rather than the while loop? I find that easier

Comment: Yeah, just tried the foreach over the lines, same effect, it seems to hiccup when the ***.xml line is first.

Comment: have you tried adding a delimiter that you can explode on so you make sure you're catching your $site variable correctly?

Comment: I can try that next.  I made the text file in Windows notepad, and i byte inspected it and the lines are registering as char(13)+char(10) CRLF.  I believe PHP only accepts char(10)?  Is the rogue char(13) sticking around in the string?

Comment: Thanks Brad, the delimiter explode technique worked.  So I went back to the original code and changed '$site  = fgets($file_handle);' to '$site  = str_replace(chr(13),'',fgets($file_handle));' and it works now.  Seems simplexml_load_file is not ok with url1.com/test1.xml and the chr(13) attatched (but is ok with url2.com/test2 with chr(13) attached)

Comment: cool.  i'll make it an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your text file to a csv then explode contents of the file on the delimiter:

```
http://www.url1.com/test1.xml,
http://www.url2.com/test2

$file = fopen("sites.txt", "r"); 
$files = explode(",", $file);
```

Sounds like there are some other things going on in addition to this but that you may have that sorted out...